# Change background tabs in ViewPager v4

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm trying to change the color of the tabs viewpager but I've tried everything and do not change color.
This is the activity I'm trying to customize the tabs: LocationsActivity.java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.jad.pholoc.util.LocationsFragmentPagerAdapter;


public class LocationsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ViewPager mPager;
    public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private LocationsFragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter;
    private ActionBar mActionbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_locations);

        mActionbar = getSupportActionBar();

        mActionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                mActionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        };

        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);


        fragmentPagerAdapter = new LocationsFragmentPagerAdapter(
                fragmentManager);

        mPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);

        mActionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            }
        };

        Tab tab = mActionbar.newTab().setText("Lista")
                .setTabListener(tabListener);

        mActionbar.addTab(tab);

        tab = mActionbar.newTab().setText("Mapa").setTabListener(tabListener);

        mActionbar.addTab(tab);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.locations, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.acercade) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, AcercaDeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

activity_locations.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleBarTextColor</item>
        <item name="background">@color/blue_pholoc</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/blue_pholoc</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleBarTextColor" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

     <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

The current appearance of the activity is this (image):

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30731371/LocationsActivity.png

As I said, I want to change the color of the tabs, but it is impossible, just look gray.

PD: I'm Spanish and I do not write well in English (Google Translate).

Comment: I have partly solved the problem, I changed the color of the tabs but not the line below the tabs indicating the selected tab.

Comment: I changed the color of the tabs changing android:backgroundStacked to backgroundStacked in ActionBarStyle style. Now I want to change the color of the line below the tabs to white but I am not able to change.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using this library: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip ?

Then you can just set the colour like this in your layout:

```
android:background="@color/memrise_blue"
```

Much easier, it also reduces your code :)

Comment: The problem is that the style for some reason does not apply to the tabs and I want to solve.